# How to get master_secret after TLS handshake

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, tls1.2

I am using apache.httpcomponent.httpcore and httpclient version 4.3 to do the TLS handshake with my https server.
Then I want to implement TLS Key Exporter (from [RFC 5705](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5705#page-4)).

Exporter uses TLS Pseudorandom Function to generate a pseudorandom bit string. It needs master_secret, server_random and client_random. Below is the function formula:

> PRF(SecurityParameters.master_secret, label,
> SecurityParameters.client_random +  SecurityParameters.server_random
>
> - ```
>   context_value_length + context_value(optional) ) [length]
>   ```

By the definition in Security Parameter of [RFC5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-77), these security parameters are determined by the TLS Handshake Protocol. So after the handshake, these security parameters should be generated.

My question is how to get these security parameters after handshake complete? Is there any library that I can use to fetch them?

Or is there any library that can generate the output of TLS Key Exporter?